# Override toString in StackClass

Tags: java

I have a program that implements a print queue. I have a StackClass that finds stackjob and stackcycle, but when I try to print these values, I get weird results, like hashtags. I know that I need to override `toString()`, but I can't get my code to compile when I add in the extra code.

I can't add the code inside my StackClass, because stackjob and stackcycle do not exist there. They exist in the PrintQueue file, which is my main method file. However, I cannot add the code within the main method because I get this error: PrintQ.java:10: ';' expected public String toString() { ^ and I can't add the code outside of the main method because I get: cannot find symbol error for both stackjob and stackcycle. Am I missing something?

I did the same in my Cycle class for jobNumber and cycleNumber and it works perfectly:

```
@Override
public String toString() 
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(jobNumber + " ");
    sb.append(cycleNumber);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Below, stackjob and stackcycle are the values I need to override toString for.. any advice?

```
StackClass<Integer> stackjob   = new StackClass();
StackClass<Integer> stackcycle = new StackClass();
```

Here is my StackClass

```
       public class StackClass<T> implements StackADT<T>
       {
       private int maxStackSize;  //variable to store the
                           //maximum stack size
       private int stackTop;      //variable to point to
                           //the top of the stack
        private T[] list;  //array of reference variables
   //Create an array of the size 100 to implement the stack.
   //Postcondition: The variable list contains the base
   //               address of the array, stackTop = 0,
   //               and maxStackSize = 100.
  public StackClass()
  {
     maxStackSize = 100;
     stackTop = 0;         //set stackTop to 0
     list = (T[]) new Object[maxStackSize]; //create the array
  }//end default constructor

   //Constructor with a parameter
   //Create an array of the size stackSize to implement the
   //stack.
   //Postcondition: The variable list contains the base
   //               address of the array, stackTop = 0,
   //               and maxStackSize = stackSize.
  public StackClass(int stackSize)
  {
     if (stackSize <= 0)
     {
        System.err.println("The size of the array to "
                         + "implement the stack must be "
                         + "positive.");
        System.err.println("Creating an array of the size 100.");

        maxStackSize = 100;
     }
     else
        maxStackSize = stackSize; //set the stack size to
                                  //the value specified by
                                  //the parameter stackSize
     stackTop = 0;    //set stackTop to 0
     list = (T[]) new Object[maxStackSize]; //create the array
  }//end constructor

   //Method to initialize the stack to an empty state.
   //Postcondition: stackTop = 0
  public void initializeStack()
  {
     for (int i = 0; i < stackTop; i++)
        list[i] = null;

     stackTop = 0;
  }//end initializeStack

   //Method to determine whether the stack is empty.
   //Postcondition: Returns true if the stack is empty;
   //               otherwise, returns false.
  public boolean isEmptyStack()
  {
     return (stackTop == 0);
  }//end isEmptyStack

   //Method to determine whether the stack is full.
   //Postcondition: Returns true if the stack is full;
   //               otherwise, returns false.
  public boolean isFullStack()
  {
     return (stackTop == maxStackSize);
  }//end isFullStack

   //Method to add newItem to the stack.
   //Precondition: The stack exists and is not full.
   //Postcondition: The stack is changed and newItem
   //               is added to the top of stack.
   //               If the stack is full, the method
   //               throws StackOverflowException
  public void push(T newItem) throws StackOverflowException
  {
     if (isFullStack())
        throw new StackOverflowException();

     list[stackTop] = newItem; //add newItem at the
                              //top of the stack
     stackTop++;               //increment stackTop
  }//end push

   //Method to return a reference to the top element of
   //the stack.
   //Precondition: The stack exists and is not empty.
   //Postcondition: If the stack is empty, the method
   //               throws StackUnderflowException;
   //               otherwise, a reference to the top
   //               element of the stack is returned.
  public T peek() throws StackUnderflowException
  {
     if (isEmptyStack())
        throw new StackUnderflowException();

     return (T) list[stackTop - 1];
  }//end peek

   //Method to remove the top element of the stack.
   //Precondition: The stack exists and is not empty.
   //Postcondition: The stack is changed and the top
   //               element is removed from the stack.
   //               If the stack is empty, the method
   //               throws StackUnderflowException
  public void pop() throws StackUnderflowException
  {
     if (isEmptyStack())
        throw new StackUnderflowException();

     stackTop--;       //decrement stackTop
     list[stackTop] = null;
  }//end pop
```

}

And here is my PrintQ :

```
             import java.io.*;
               import java.util.*;

            public class PrintQ {


  public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {

     String job1;

     int firstComma;
     int secondComma;

     QueueClass<Cycle> list= new QueueClass(100);
     QueueClass<Integer> cyclelist= new QueueClass(100);
     Cycle currentcycle= new Cycle();
     Cycle priorityCycle= new Cycle();
     Cycle Scycle= new Cycle();

     try{

        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Whitney\\Desktop\\QueueIn.txt");
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine;
        job1=br.readLine();
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
           switch(job1.charAt(0)) {

              case 'q': 
                 {
                    System.out.println("loop q");
                    firstComma=job1.indexOf(',');
                    secondComma=job1.lastIndexOf(',');
                    currentcycle.jobNumber=Integer.parseInt(job1.substring(firstComma+1,secondComma));
                    currentcycle.cycleNumber=Integer.parseInt(job1.substring(secondComma+1));
                    cyclelist.addQueue(currentcycle.cycleNumber);
                    list.addQueue(currentcycle);

                    while(currentcycle.cycleNumber > 0)
                    {

                       System.out.println(currentcycle.jobNumber + " "  + currentcycle.cycleNumber);
                       currentcycle.cycleNumber--;
                    }
                    //list.print();
                    break;
                 }

              case 'p': 
                 {    System.out.println("loop priority");                
                    firstComma=job1.indexOf(',');
                    secondComma=job1.lastIndexOf(',');
                    priorityCycle.jobNumber=Integer.parseInt(job1.substring(firstComma+1,secondComma));
                    priorityCycle.cycleNumber=Integer.parseInt(job1.substring(secondComma+1));
                    cyclelist.addQueue(priorityCycle.cycleNumber);
                    list.priorityinsert(priorityCycle);
                    while(priorityCycle.cycleNumber > 0)
                    {
                       System.out.println(priorityCycle.jobNumber + " "  + priorityCycle.cycleNumber);
                       priorityCycle.cycleNumber--;

                    }
                    System.out.println(cyclelist);                     
                    //list.print();

                    break;
                 }

              case 's': 
                 {System.out.println("loop s");
                    firstComma=job1.indexOf(',');
                    Scycle.cycleNumber=Integer.parseInt(job1.substring(firstComma+1));
                    cyclelist.addQueue(Scycle.cycleNumber);                       
                    list.addQueue(Scycle);
                    while(Scycle.cycleNumber > 0)
                    {
                       System.out.println(Scycle.jobNumber + " "  + Scycle.cycleNumber);
                       Scycle.cycleNumber--;

                    }


                    break;
                 }

              case 'h': 
                 {
                    System.out.println("loop halt");
                    StackClass<Integer> stackjob= new StackClass();
                    StackClass<Integer> stackcycle= new StackClass();



                    job1=(String) br.readLine();
                    //list.print();

                    System.out.println(stackjob.toString() +" " + stackcycle.toString());


                    while((strLine = br.readLine()) != null){

                       switch(job1.charAt(0)) {

                          case 'q':
                             {

                                firstComma=job1.indexOf(',');
                                secondComma=job1.lastIndexOf(',');
                                currentcycle.jobNumber=Integer.parseInt(job1.substring(firstComma+1,secondComma));
                                currentcycle.cycleNumber=Integer.parseInt(job1.substring(secondComma+1));
                                stackjob.push(currentcycle.jobNumber);
                                stackcycle.push(currentcycle.cycleNumber);
                                System.out.println("hi");
                                System.out.println(currentcycle.jobNumber + " "  + currentcycle.cycleNumber);
                                //list.print();
                                break;
                             }
                          case 'p':
                             {

                                firstComma=job1.indexOf(',');
                                secondComma=job1.lastIndexOf(',');
                                priorityCycle.jobNumber=Integer.parseInt(job1.substring(firstComma+1,secondComma));
                                priorityCycle.cycleNumber=Integer.parseInt(job1.substring(secondComma+1));
                                stackjob.push(priorityCycle.jobNumber);
                                stackcycle.push(priorityCycle.cycleNumber);
                                System.out.println(priorityCycle.jobNumber-- + " "  + priorityCycle.cycleNumber--);
                                break;
                             }

                          case 's':
                             {
                                firstComma=job1.indexOf(',');
                                secondComma=job1.lastIndexOf(',');
                                Scycle.cycleNumber=Integer.parseInt(job1.substring(secondComma+1));
                                stackjob.push(0);
                                stackcycle.push(Scycle.cycleNumber);
                                System.out.println(Scycle.jobNumber + " " + Scycle.cycleNumber); 
                                break;
                             }

                          case 'h': 
                             {
                                System.out.println("Halt - " + list);
                                continue;
                             }

                       }
                       job1=(String) br.readLine();

                    }   
                    //System.out.println();

                    while((stackjob.isEmptyStack()==false) || (stackcycle.isEmptyStack()==false)) 
                    { 
                       int printjob;
                       int printcycle;
                       Object peek;

                       printjob=stackjob.peek();
                       printcycle=stackcycle.peek();
                       stackcycle.pop();
                       stackjob.pop(); 
                       System.out.println("Job Number: "+printjob+" "+"Cycles Remaining: "+printcycle);
                    } 


                    continue;
                 }           
           }
           job1=br.readLine();
        }
        in.close();
     }
        catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
           System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }


     Cycle whilecurrent= new Cycle();

     while(list.isEmptyQueue()==false) 
     {
        whilecurrent=list.front();
        int whilecurrentcycle= cyclelist.front();
        //list.print();
        //System.out.println();

        //while(whilecurrentcycle != 0)
        //{
           //System.out.println();//"loop "+whilecurrentcycle--);  
        //}
        //System.out.println();

        //System.out.println(whilecurrent);

        cyclelist.deleteQueue();
        list.deleteQueue();   
     }  

     list.print();

  }
```

}

Comment: What is the compilation error?

Comment: @YogendraSingh: It looks like we're supposed to be able to read the original poster's mind and guess the error. I give up.

Comment: Well, I can't add the code inside my StackClass, because stackjob and stackcycle do not exist there. They exist in the PrintQueue file, which is my main method file. However, I cannot add the code within the main method because I get this error:      PrintQ.java:10: ';' expected
      public String toString() {
                            ^
and I can't add the code outside of the main method because I get: cannot find symbol error for both stackjob and stackcycle. Am I missing something?

Comment: Consider posting the entire code of `StackClass` or an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) version of your code. This will help us understand your problem. Also, when you're using `append()`, don't use a `+` operator. In your case, it wouldn't be a big deal but using a + within a StringBuffer would reduce the advantage of actually using this class in the first place. Consider something like this: `sb.append(jobNumber).append(" ");`

Comment: Your comment should be an edit to  your original question. Show the code show all of the error. You're still not telling us near enough.

Comment: I don't see where you've attempted a `toString()` method override attempt in your StackClass. And this statement, `"can't add the code inside my StackClass, because stackjob and stackcycle do not exist there."` makes no sense. A toString() method won't need to know this information.

Comment: I deleted all of my attempts. I told you where I tried to place the code and got error. In my Cycle class, I had to override toString() for jobNumber and cycleNumber, so I assumed it would be the same for stackjob and stackcycle. But I'm not having any luck.

Comment: I haven't used override toString before this assignment so I guess I dont completely understand it.

Comment: No, you don't need to override for jobNumber or cycleNumber, you just need to override it for the StackClass, that's it. Again this makes no sense. I assume that you want the toString to show the Integers held by yours stacks, so do that: as mentioned in one deleted answer, cycle through the stack using a loop, gather the Integer values in a StringBuilder, and return the toString of this StringBuilder. I'm still unsure where you may be stuck.

Comment: Actually you'll not be accumulating Integers, it will be the toString representation of whatever object type your stack holds since it is a generic stack.

Comment: OK I think Ive got it, thanks

Comment: This question is too difficult to read, and unlikely to be of any use to anyone other than the OP.  "Too localized".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the stack array, building up a string:

```
public String toString() {
  StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder("[");
  if ( stackTop > 0 ) {
     for (int i = stackTop - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if ( i == 0 ) {
           output.append(list[i].toString());
        }
        else {
           output.append(list[i].toString() + "|");
        }
     }
  }
  output.append("]");
  return output.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a short-cut solution, you could always return the Arrays.toString(...) of your list:

```
public String toString() {
  return java.util.Arrays.toString(list);
}
```

Otherwise simply iterate through the list array in your toString method and add the toString() returned by the list items into your StringBuilder.